# variable fillna() in each column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, imputation, fillna

For starters, here is some artificial data fitting my problem:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(vsize, 10)), 
          columns = ["col_{}".format(x) for x in range(10)], 
          index = range(0, vsize * 3, 3))

df_2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(vsize, 10)), 
            columns = ["col_{}".format(x) for x in range(10, 20, 1)], 
            index = range(0, vsize * 2, 2))

df = df.merge(df_2, left_index = True, right_index = True, how = 'outer')

df_tar = pd.DataFrame({"tar_1": [np.random.randint(0, 2) for x in range(vsize * 3)], 
               "tar_2": [np.random.randint(0, 4) for x in range(vsize * 3)], 
               "tar_3": [np.random.randint(0, 8) for x in range(vsize * 3)], 
               "tar_4": [np.random.randint(0, 16) for x in range(vsize * 3)]})

df = df.merge(df_tar, left_index = True, right_index = True, how = 'inner')
```

Now, I would like to fill NaN values in each column, with a MEDIAN value of non-NaN values in each column, but **with noise added to each filled NaN in that column**. The MEDIAN value should be calculated for values in that column, which belong to the same class, as marked in column tar_4 at first. Then, if any NaNs persist in the column (because some values in the column were all in tar_4 class which featured only NaNs, so no MEDIAN could be calculated), the same operation is repeated on the updated column (with some NaN's already filled in from tar_4 operation), but with values belonging to the same class relative to tar_3 column. Then tar_2, and tar_1.

The way I imagine it would be as follows:

- col_1 features e.g. 6 non-Nan & 4 NaN values: [1, 2, NaN, 4, NaN, 12, 5, NaN, 1, NaN]
- only values [1, 2, NaN, 4, NaN] belong to the same class (e.g. class 1) in tar_4, so they are pushed through NaN filling:

  - NaN value at index [2] gets filled with MEDIAN (=2) + random(-3, 3) * std error of distribution in col_1, e.g. 2 + (1 * 1.24)
  - NaN value at index [4] gets filled with MEDIAN (=2) + random(-3, 3) * std error of distribution in col_1, e.g. 2 + (-2 * 1.24)
- Now col_1 has the following 8 non-NaN and 2 NaN values: [1, 2, 1.24, 4, -0.48, 12, 5, NaN, 1, NaN]
- Column col_1 still features some NaN values, so grouping based on common class in tar_3 column is applied:

  - out of [1, 2, 1.24, 4, -0.48, 12, 5, NaN, 1, NaN], values [1, 2, 1.24, 4, -0.48, 12, 5, NaN] are in the same class now, so they get processed:
  - NaN value at index [7] gets assigned MEDIAN of values in indices [0-6] (=2) + random(-3, 3) * std error, e.g. 2 + 2 * 3.86
- now col_1 has 9 non-NaN values and 1 NaN value: [1, 2, 1.24, 4, -0.48, 12, 5, 9.72, 1, NaN]

  - all values in col_1 belong to the same class based on tar_2 column, so NaN value at index [9] gets processed with the same logic, as described above, and ends up with value 2 * (-1 * 4.05)
- col_1 now features only non-NaN values: [1, 2, 1.24, 4, -0.48, 12, 5, 9.72, 1, -6.09], and does not need to to be pushed through NaN filling based on tar_1 column.

The same logic goes through the rest of columns.

So, the **expected output:** DataFrame with filled NaN values, in each column based on decreasing level of granularity of classes based on columns tar_4 - tar_1.

I already have a code, which kind of achieves that, thanks to @Quang Hoang:

```
def min_max_check(col):
    if ((df[col].dropna() >= 0) & (df[col].dropna() <= 1.0)).all():
        return medians[col]
    elif (df[col].dropna() >= 0).all():
        return medians[col] + round(np.random.randint(low = 0, high = 3) * stds[col], 2)
    else:
        return medians[col] + round(np.random.randint(low = -3, high = 3) * stds[col], 2)


tar_list = ['tar_4', 'tar_3', 'tar_2', 'tar_1']
cols = [col for col in df.columns if col not in tar_list]
# since your dataframe may not have continuous index
idx = df.index

for tar in tar_list:
    medians = df[cols].groupby(by = df[tar]).agg('median')
    std = df[cols].groupby(by = df[tar]).agg(np.std)
    df.set_index(tar, inplace=True)
    for col in cols:
        df[col] = df[col].fillna(min_max_check(col))
    df.reset_index(inplace=True)

df.index = idx
```

However, this only fills the NaN values with the same MEDIAN value + noise, at each granularity level. How can this code be enhanced to generate varied fill values for each NaN value at e.g. tar_4, tar_3, tar_2 and tar_1 levels?

Answer (score 0):

One quick solution is to modify your `min_max_check` to `get_noise` at each row:

```
def gen_noise(col):
    num_row = len(df)

    # generate noise of the same height as our dataset
    # notice the size argument in randint
    if ((df[col].dropna() >= 0) & (df[col].dropna() <= 1.0)).all():
        noise = 0
    elif (df[col].dropna() >= 0).all():
        noise =  np.random.randint(low = 0, 
                                   high = 3, 
                                   size=num_row)
    else:
        noise =  np.random.randint(low = -3, 
                                   high = 3,
                                   size=num_row)

    # multiplication with isna() forces those at non-null values in df[col] to be 0
    return noise * df[col].isna()
```

And then later:

```
df.set_index(tar, inplace=True)

for col in cols[:1]:
    noise = gen_noise(col)
    df[col] = (df[col].fillna(medians[col])
                      .add(noise.mul(stds[col]).values)
              )

df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

---

Note: You can modify the code further in the sense that you generate the `noise_df` with the same size with `medians` and `stds`, something like this

```
for tar in tar_list:
    medians = df[cols].groupby(df[tar]).agg('median')
    stds = df[cols].groupby(df[tar]).agg('std')

    # generate noise_df here
    medians = medians + round(noise_df*std, 2)

    df.set_index(tar, inplace=True)

    for col in cols[:1]:
        df[col] = df[col].fillna(medians[col])    

    df.reset_index(inplace=True)

df.index = idx
```

Comment: Hi Quang, and thank you for your answer. However, are you sure that the code above actually makes each NaN in e.g. col_1 get a different noise during each tar_X grouping? The way I read the code at the moment, min_max_check() modification you suggested will still just add the same noise to each NaN instance of the same medians.index.

Comment: No, noise is generated with `size=num_row`, so it is a vector of the same size with `median[col]`.

Comment: My point is something else. The way I am looking at the current logic, I think what is happening is that: 1) noise multiplier is generated with np.random.randint() as a vector for all e.g. 'tar_4' classes, since they are the index of the medians DataFrame; 2) noise multiplier is multiplied vector-wise with DataFrame of STD values, which is also using tar_4 classes as its indices; 3) these values are then mapped back to the df via fillna() method, which operates on df with index temporarily set to tar_4 classes. That means that every class e.g. "4" in df's index still gets the same noise.

Comment: @Greem666 fix found, quite simple. See edited answer.